# Clarification for Bash documentation on disown builtin option -h

Tags: bash, signals, job-control, disown

According to the documentation:

> To prevent the shell from sending the SIGHUP signal to a particular
>   job, it should be removed from the jobs table with the disown builtin
>   **or** marked to not receive SIGHUP using disown -h.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Signals.html

Note the **OR** in the quote.

I can confirm that simply using `disown` without `-h` and re-logging that the process did not exit:

```
#!/bin/bash

( sleep 10s; echo 1 > b ) &
disown
```

It seems that the `-h` option is not necessary? If it works without then what is its purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without `-h` the job is removed from the table of active jobs, with `-h` it is not.

Everything is in the manual:

```
 disown [-ar] [-h] [jobspec ...]

       (...)
       If the -h option is given, each jobspec is not removed
       from the table, but is marked so that SIGHUP is not sent to the
       job  if  the shell  receives  a SIGHUP.
```

To see the difference run `jobs` after disowning the job with and without `-h`.

Comment: I was reading the gnu.org manual which I've added a link to below the quote in my post. This is MUCH clearer.